# Small error when taking modulo

Tags: c++, modulo, largenumber

I've written a little algorithm which calculates a series of numbers, but they eventually get to big to store in an `unsigned long long`. This is why I've decided to take the modulo every time the next number is calculated. This is my function:

```
#define MOD 1000000007

template <typename T>
T modpow(T base, T exp, T modulus) {
    base %= modulus;
    T result = 1;
    while (exp > 0) {
        if (exp & 1) result = (result * base) % modulus;
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
        exp >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

vector<unsigned long long> B(int n) {
    vector<unsigned long long> points;
    vector<unsigned long long> cum_points;

    points.push_back(0);
    points.push_back(0);

    cum_points = points;

    unsigned long long prev = 0;
    if (n >= 2){
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
            prev += cum_points[i];
            prev %= MOD;
            points.push_back((modpow((unsigned long long)2, (unsigned long long)i, (unsigned long long) MOD)+prev)%MOD);
            cum_points.push_back((cum_points[i+1]+points[i+2])%MOD);
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

This returns a vector with a series of numbers:

0,
0,
1,
2,
5,
12,
28,
64,
144,
320,
704,
1536,
3328,
...

And so on...

The problem is that when `n > 50` the modulo is slightly off:
(The first values are the ones calculated without the modulo in the code, and the values after the equal signs are the results with the modulo in the code.)

```
50: 1759218604441600 % 1000000007 = 592127074; this is the right answer
51: 3588805953060860 % 1000000007 = 927939229; this should be: 927939225
```

The error gets a bit larger every time `n` gets higher. Where does this little offset come from?

Some possible problems:

- The `modpow()` somehow doesn't give the right answer when the numbers
  exceed a       certain length. **This is not the problem**
- There is some mistake made with the math, however I do believe I used the following equations the right way:

`(a*b) mod c = ((a mod c)*(b mod c)) mod c`

`(a + b) mod c = ((a mod c)+(b mod c)) mod c`

- I could also have a wrong variable type in my code, although I wouldn't know where.

**EDIT:** I've ruled out some of the possible problems and the problem seems to lie within the calculation of `prev` when `i == 48`.

Answer (score -1):

You could check whether your modulus is small enough. Have you checked the size of an unsigned long long on your system?

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max();
```

When you check that, you might as well also check the size of an unsigned int
at the same time. I'm not sure they are necessarily different.

Your modulus has 10 digits, so a product of two numbers could have up to 20 digits.  If your max unsigned long long is smaller than MOD * MOD, then you could be getting an overflow error.

An error in your formula would probably show up before n = 51.

Comments:
If you are using the C++11 standard, why not replace that macro with

```
constexpr unsigned long long MOD = 1000000007;
```

Also, in the spot where you call modpow, you could avoid all those casts to `unsigned long long` by simply calling the specific function that you want:
`modpow<unsigned long long>`. Then the arguments will be converted to the right type automatically.

Comment: The maximum size of an unsigned long long on my system is: `18446744073709551615`, which should be large enough for the modulo operations. (`unsigned int`: 4294967295). The `constexpr` does not work as it is not yet supported by VS 2013.